# AJAX autocomplete with jQuery in a Ruby on Rails 3 application

Tags: jquery, ajax, autocomplete, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to implement an AJAX "autocomplete search" feature of my Ruby on Rails 3 application. I would like to use jQuery to implement the JavaScript portion.

Is there a popular approach (or tutorial) to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Railscast #205 might help: [unobtrusive javascript](http://railscasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution which I would definitely recommend is using [rails3-jquery-autocomplete](https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete).

Comment: There are lot of problems setting up this gem and working with it as i tried a lot of solutions but none works